# jquery convert content url to file url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am picking the media from the android gallery , and I am getting the url of the media as a `content://media/....` but I required the url type as a file url .

So the format of the url is should be like : `file://media/...`  .

so is there any api is jquery or javascript to convert **content url to file url** or It will work with simple replace of string operation ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such method in JS/jquery. You have to use String's `replace`, or `substr`/`slice` with `indexOf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple replace should work just fine:

```
var sUrl = "content://media/";
sUrl = sUrl.replace('content://', 'file://');
```